# After getting value assign first time for let variable its value is not getting change #JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, razor-pages, asp.net-core-5.0

I've created the click event in that after click the pop up gets open. And in that pop their is a statement in which I've changing the **enable** and **disable** keyword dynamically  so, when I run the server for first time, the value is get assign to **let** variable but after clicking on the same button the value of variable is doesn't get change in the pop up box.

**HTML**

```
<div class="modal" id="action-confirm-box" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                @*<h5 class="modal-title">%MODALNAME%</h5>*@
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Do you want to %STATUS% the rule with Options ?</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" id="continue-confirm-box" class="btn btn-primary">Continue</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
const changeStatusText = function (value) {
            let statusText = $('#action-confirm-box').find('div.modal-body').html();
            if (value) {
                console.log("Inside IF");
                statusText = statusText.replace('%STATUS%', 'disable');
            }
            else {
                console.log("Inside else");
                statusText = statusText.replace('%STATUS%', 'enable');
            }
            $('#action-confirm-box').find('div.modal-body').html(statusText);
        };
```

So In this when code get run and we click on button the pop gets open for first time and **%STATUS%** value get assign but on 2nd click the **%STATUS%** value is remaining same for If and else statement. I didn't getting what's wrong here

```
const operateEvents = {
            'click .btn-icon': function (e, value, row, index) {
                console.log("operateEvents  ", row);
                changeStatusText(row.enabled);
                    $('#action-confirm-box').modal('show');
                    
                $('#continue-confirm-box').click(() => changeStatus(row, index));
                
            }
        };
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to give the status text `<p>` element an ID and just edit the `innerText` rather than the HTML? This seems like a strange way of doing things.

Comment: We also only seem to have half the problem here. Please show where `changeStatusText ` is called, preferably as a [mcve], don't make us guess what is missing.

Comment: Once you have replaces `'%STATUS%` the first time it is no longer there to replace again.

Comment: @JonP I want to change the %STATUS% whenever user click on button and also wants it to change according to value assign in if and else statement

Answer (score 0):

Add an element in the html to update the content

```
<div class="modal" id="action-confirm-box" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                @*<h5 class="modal-title">%MODALNAME%</h5>*@
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Do you want to <span class="status_text">%STATUS%</span> the rule with Options ?</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" id="continue-confirm-box" class="btn btn-primary">Continue</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then update the content of that element via javascript

```
const changeStatusText = function (value) {
            //Use the ternary operator to toggle the text
            $('#action-confirm-box .status_text').html(value ? "disable" : "enable");
}
```